# How to find a conditional mean using R

Tags: r, mean

I would like to find the mean of wages for males and females. How do i find the compute mean for wages that belong in the female column and for wages that belong in the male column.

Answer (score 2):

Please always ask your question in a reproducible fashion.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Regarding your question, I'm using the `mtcars` dataset as an example, and assuming you have all female values in one column in another (like we have `mpg` and `cyl` here), then you could use the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = c(mpg,cyl),.fns = mean))
```

or for your question, assuming that your dataset is called `df` and your columns are called `female` and `male`:

```
df %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = c(female,male),.fns = mean))
```

If, however, your data was organised differently and you had gender in one separate column and e.g. the value you want to take the mean for in a column called `value`, then you should do:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(vs) %>% 
  summarise(resulting_mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
```

Where we have calculated the mean `mpg` by `vs`.
In your case this might be

```
df %>%
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  summarise(resulting_mean_value = mean(value))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `colMeans` in `base R` after selecting the columns of interest

```
colMeans(df1[c('male', 'female')], na.rm = TRUE)
```